# Edit which "isolates issue" rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

This question [Evaluate expression in parentheses, in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462378/evaluate-expression-in-parentheses-in-string) was closed for being too broad. I tried to isolate an issue which OP probably thought of (while not explicitly defining it), however, the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11936432) was rejected. The reason stated was

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

However, the goal of that edit was not to make it easier to read, but to isolate an issue, which may have the side-effect of making it less readable.

Is there any policy I am missing? Was the edit itself not clarifying the question, or was even with that addition too broad, or do you have have to edit somehow else when you want it to be reopened?

Answer (score 4):

> I tried to isolate an issue which OP probably thought of (while not explicitly defining it)

That's where you went wrong. Don't think for the OP. If they forget to mention a requirement in their question, it's their problem. For all we know, they *do* want to write a full-blown mathematical expression parser.

It would be fine if the text from your edit could be extracted from a discussion in comments, but as far as I can see, that did not happen.